# Regexp alias to match any route

Tags: regex, ubuntu, nginx, alias

I'm trying to create an alias to any request of css get to my current css, something like

```
location = /static/css/app.*.css {
  alias /static/css/app.93d22c20a71b3ace1635a455418a4462.css;
  break;
}
```

So there the * indicates that any app.000000.css requests go to my current CSS, is that possible? Would appreciate any help on that

Update -

I tried something like

```
location ~* ^/static/css/(\app.+\.css) {
    alias /static/css/app.93d22c20a71b3ace1635a455418a4462.css;
    break;
  }
```

did not work so far

Comment: What is the `root` set to? You should probably be using: `try_files /static/css/app.93d22c20a71b3ace1635a455418a4462.css =404;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution that I found

```
location ~ ^/static/css/(app.*) {
    alias /static/css/app.93d22c20a71b3ace1635a455418a4462.css;
    break;
  }
```